# Making changes to SharePoint Designer 2010 workflows in Prod

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflows in production environment and we need to make changes to them. There are list items on which the workflows are running already...

Can you please let me know the recommended way of making changes to prod environment SPD 2010 workflows?

I would like to make the changes in a dev environment and migrate only the workflows over to production. And I would like the existing workflows not to break!

Can this be done without having to recreate the list or site?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Kindly follow the answer provided in following post

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/a7f8edfd-376c-41e1-9d4e-838f61981e7f